# addEventListerner not detected

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to build an expandable panels. I want to have two panels which will be open/closed based on the user selection. Running the following code:

```
const classes = {
  isOpen: ".js-is-open"
};
const selectors = {
  panelTrigger: ".js-expandablePanel__title"
};
function expandablePanel() {
  document.querySelector(selectors.panelTrigger).addEventListener("click", () => { 
    console.log('dfgdfgdf');
    console.log(classes.isOpen);
  });
  console.log(selectors.panelTrigger);
  console.log(classes.isOpen);
}
export { expandablePanel };
```

comes up with the following error:

```
ExpandablePanel.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at expandablePanel (ExpandablePanel.js:9)
at Object.defineProperty.value (ContentAuthoring.js:13)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 29b82058c7ef95bf1e58:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:10)
at Object.defineProperty.value (main.bundle.js:53996)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 29b82058c7ef95bf1e58:19)
at Object.defineProperty.value (index.js:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 29b82058c7ef95bf1e58:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (formats.js:18)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 29b82058c7ef95bf1e58:19)
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="js-expandablePanel__title">
    <p>
      Demo title 1
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="js-expandablePanel">
   Demo panel 1
  </div>
   <div class="js-expandablePanel__title">
    <p>
      Demo title 1
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="js-expandablePanel">
   Demo panel 1
  </div>
```

Can you see any obvious reasons why it doesn't like my `addEventListener`?

Comment: It tells you right in the error message, your DOM selection is returning `null`.

Comment: Is `js-expandablePanel__title` a class name? In that case you are missing a `.` (`.js-expandablePanel__title`)

Comment: @BalázsÉdes I have added that but it is still not  solved

Comment: @John: You haven't provided an actual demonstration of an issue. We don't know what you're selecting and from where. When you post an example, first check that it *fully* reproduces the issue with the minimal code necessary.

Comment: Why don't you create a fiddle demonstrating the error?

Comment: Please don't "create a fiddle" (assuming you know what that means). Just give us relevant data.

Comment: document.querySelector is telling you that you don’t have an element with class =  js-expandablePanel__title

Comment: @rockstar i have updated my question. What I am trying to do is assign click value to ".js-expandablePanel__tiltle"

Comment: That's still not a full demonstration, but it's *more likely* now that you're running the JS code before the DOM is loaded, but again, we really can't tell from these various fragments.

Comment: @James please look at my HTML and you will see it

Comment: John, does that element exist at the moment the script is being executed?

Comment: @James yes it is

Comment: Can you just do this.. With nothing else in that function.. It will come back with null.... 
function expandablePanel() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.js-expandablePanel__title'))
}

Comment: @John: If the element exists *when it runs*, and that is the correct class name, then there's no error related to that code, and all is well.

Comment: John, please show where the script is being executed (should be in document.ready or in a script tag occurring after the html element it’s trying to manipulate)

Answer (score 0):

You need a (.)

```
const selectors = {
  panelTrigger: ".js-expandablePanel__title"
};
```

Comment: Try just console logging --> document.querySelector('.js-expandablePanel__title');

Comment: Also how are you using the function and at what point? The error is clear, it's simply can't add an event listener to nothing, so either that element doesn't exist on the page or doesn't exist when you are trying to use it.

Comment: not sure why is down voted. What I am trying to do is assign a click event on the ".js-expandablePanel__title" selector when clicked

Comment: I down voted it because 1) there wasn't (and still isn't) enough info in the question to give a reasonable answer, and 2) the question has been updated to show that this was indeed not the issue.

Comment: Unless it gets voted back up I've kind of lost interest (hint) haha - Show me where the code looks like for 'js-expandablePanel__title' i.e. where you are defining that html

Comment: @rockstar - my answer was correct though.. Despite not fixing his problem, it's unearthered another but doesn't warrant a downvote. If anything downvote the question

Comment: Sure it does. At first, it was just a guess, which may or may not have been correct. Furthermore, it didn't fully solve the actual issue, and is entirely obsolete now. You've acknowledged that there's important info missing, so you risk getting down voted when you do that. Not my fault that you decided to jump the gun. Besides all that, it gave no explanation of *why* a `.` was needed.

Comment: ...and I did down vote the question. Why haven't you?